# Fixing Fortify Cross-Site Scripting: Persistent Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, xss, fortify

The last line of below code in my spring boot application, fortify giving XSS error.

```
    E body;
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest.Builder builder = ....
    builder.POST(BodyPublishers.ofString((String)body)); 
    return client.send(builder.build(), BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

**Error Details**

1. Data enters a web application through an untrusted source. In the case of persistent (also known as stored) XSS, the untrusted source is typically a database or other back-end data store, while in the case of reflected XSS it is typically a web request.
2. The data is included in dynamic content that is sent to a web user without validation.

I understand that the we need to validate the user input and encode/sanitize the output to fix this issue. Is there any recommended library to sanitize the data ( body variable) or any other alternative to fix the issue ?. I'm thinking to use JsonSanitizer or HtmlUtils.htmlEscape.

Comment: Which line has the error? Have you shared the complete error message and description? What is the question?

Comment: @Kevin could you provide the `source` and `sink`? afaik the report always give a pair for each problems.

Comment: oh right, given its on java you might consider using [owasp-born encoder](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder) instead of `JsonSanitizer`, `HtmlUtils.htmlEscape`, or anything you cook yourself - fortify sca often doesn't see custom solution as a fix.

Comment: @Bugas thank you for your reply. I will try owasp encoder. My APIs does not have the content-type set as application/json. I think in that case fortify thinks the content is in HTML. I will try setting the content type as well